# label and value from combo box using html and php

Tags: php, select, combobox, label

i have this code

```
<?php

$sexV = @$_POST['sex'];  //the value of selected option 1 and 2
$sexL = @$_POST['sex']['label'];  //the value of label of selected option male and female 

if(@$_POST['doFun']){
  echo $sexV;
}

?>
<form method="post">
<select name="sex" id="sex">
<option value="1" label="male">m</option>
<option value="2" label="female">f</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="doFun">
</form>
```

my question is ...how to get value of selected option and value of the label of the same option ??
thank you ^_^

Comment: you should use hidden input instead of using this technique

Comment: how to use hidden input ??

Comment: It's more complicated than that, let me build an answer

Comment: Can you use jQuery? or want to use Plain Javascript? because it's needed

Comment: you should define the hidden input inside the form and give it some name, so each time when a user selects the option for the `sex` you should call click function to set the hidden input dynamically based on the selected value and bingo!!

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION ONE:** Doesn't require javascript but needs parsing PHP side

```
<?php

if(@$_POST['doFun']){
  $sexVals = explode(',', $_POST['sex']);

 $sexV = $sexVals[0];  //the value of selected option 1 and 2
 $sexL = $sexVals[1];  //the value of label of selected option male and female 
  echo $sexV;
}

?>
<form method="post">
<select name="sex" id="sex">

<option value="1,male">m</option>

<option value="2,female">f</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="doFun">
</form>
```

**OPTION TWO:** Requires javascript which can be disabled by the user and all those nightmares from the clientside.

```
<form method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="sex-label" id="sex-label"/>

<select name="sex" id="sex">

<option value="1" label="male">m</option>

<option value="2" label="female">f</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="doFun">
</form>

<script>
var element = document.getElementById('sex');
var label = document.getElementById('sex-label');

element.onchange = function(){

    label.value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].getAttribute("label");

};
</script>
```

Latter in PHP...

```
$sexL = $_POST['sex-label'];
```

Comment: Of course at this point, why have the value in the html at all? And might want to move the $sexVals, $sexV, $sexL statements into the if statement.

Comment: That's true @Terminus, that way will be more UndefinedVariableError-proof haha

Comment: Just added a Clientside solution tho